# Runnig Django project outside virtual enviroment

Tags: python, django

I have made an `api` in `tastypie` `django` which uploads an image it worked perfectly inside `django` virtual environment. But when i run it outside virtual environment it doesn't work. Actually i have installed many libraries required for image processing and i want to link my work with my `api` but as those libraries could not be imported in virtual environment so is there any solution  ????

Comment: Why couldn't they be imported in your virtual environment?

Comment: because they are installed outside virtual environment

Comment: Does it give you the ImportError exception or what? Why can't they be imported?

Answer (score 0):

Just install the required packages within your virtual environment. Once you activate your virtual environment, type:

```
pip install <package name>
```

changing `<package name>` to the package you want installed.

Comment: Thanks i guess i have to install all those packages again

Comment: @user3451877 You know you can automate that? Just run pip freeze > requirements.txt in your virtualenv to dump the installed modules to a file, then run pip install -r /path/to/requirements.txt from elsewhere to install them again

Comment: @MatthewDaly True, but I think he's talking about installing all of his global packages into his virtualenv. He could do that, I suppose, but it would defeat most of purpose of virtualenv.